# Visual Studio is detecting errors while showing sources in the editor and sees no errors while producing the code for executing in debug mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors, visual-studio-debugging, vscode-debugger

I’ve changed the target platform of my WinForms application (a relatively large solution consisting of 10 interdependent projects) from x86 to x64. It is a ClickOnce application signed with a Comodo certificate; all assemblies are also signed with the same certificate. Everything went fine, no errors while I was in Release mode and I could produce a working distributable. However, I’ve got a plenty of undefined-type errors by just switching the solution configuration to Debug.

*The type or namespace name '***' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Apparently, Visual Studio could not properly process one reference (may be more than one). Errors remained the same even after I’ve deleted the contents of bin and obj directories and cleaned all projects. The strange thing is that I can start the executable in debug mode and extensively test it without any problems. However, the compiler errors remain. In other words, Visual Studio is detecting errors while showing sources in the editor and sees no errors while producing the code for executing in debug mode. The problem does not exist in the original x86 Solution which I still have on another machine. It seems that something went wrong while I was changing the configuration. To be more explicit I’ve produced 4 screenshots you can find here:

- https://www.soascape.com/issues/attachments/INT_001/release.png
- https://www.soascape.com/issues/attachments/INT_001/debug.png
- https://www.soascape.com/issues/attachments/INT_001/references.png
- https://www.soascape.com/issues/attachments/INT_001/FsB-namespace-SoaGui.png

Have I missed something while moving from x86 to x64? I’m using VS Community 2019 version 16.7.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have referenced several projects into your main project.

**As a suggestion**, you should make every project's **Configuration** is `x64` and **Configuration** is `Debug`.

**In other words**, you have to ensure that the same **Configuration** and **Platform** of your main project has been already be built with on every referenced project.

**My first thought** is that your referenced project does not build with **Debug** and did not keep the same configuration and platform with the main project. So your main project with `Debug|x64` cannot find the corresponding output files `Debug|x64`(which means that your referenced projects do not have such folder), so the issue occurs.

**In my memory**, the dll of the refenced project can only be used when the Configuration and Platform is the same of the main project. If they are not the same, they cannot be used forever. And you make sure that the referenced projects have the same output folder as the main project.

**For an example**, if you built your **Reconciler** project with `Debug|x64`, you should ensure the referenced projects has the output folder with `Debug|x64` mode.

And if it does not help, please follow the below suggestions:

**Suggestions**

**1)** close VS, delete `.vs` under every solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder of every project.

[image]

**2)** open every referenced project-->build the project with `Debug|x64` mode.

**3)** When you finish it, reopen your **Reconciler** project and you can not see such issue with `Debug|x64`.

**Besides**, if your referenced projects are lib projects, you can directly referenc the dll rather than the project.

Comment: Deleting .vs folders solved the problem. Thanks, Jack J Jun - MSFT for suggesting that. BTW, all projects were configured as x64 and I have deleted all obj and bin folders before writing this post – never thought I should also be looking into .vs folders. I guess Visual Studio should be deleting all generated files when I press “Clean” on the context menu of a project (but it does not, and it looks it doesn’t do much at all). One way or another, thanks to Jack, it seems I’m out of the woods now.